# Implementing document management with an ASP.NET MVC front-end

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, sharepoint, wss, content-management

I've implemented a website for a client that holds editable articles.

I used ASP.NET MVC and made the content manageable by storing it in a 'Content' table in the database and creating a simple Admin section of the site, where the user can add/edit/remove content and choose where on the site it will appear.

Now the client has come back wanting full document management features. They want version control, permissions, PDF export and simple workflow on all content items.

I'm debating in my head how to do this.

I found [one question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/612646/simple-document-management-system-and-api) where a lot of people recommended WSS (Windows Sharepoint Services).

The thing is, I want to build the admin interface myself and make it *really* easy for the client to use.

Will WSS allow me to do this?

Comment: "asp.net-mvc" and "asp.net" tags will give you better response on your question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

WSS has functionality for storing and versioning of documents, and workflow.

I don't think that PDF conversion is not part of WSS, but you could use a 3rd party tool.

You could use the WSS UI for the Admin site, placing documents in spesific document libraries. But for your ASP.NET MVC site you could access WSS via web services (WCF).